# Is there any log or function to know if the values in a table changed through edit?

Tags: mysql

Basically,we are in a application platform and it is using MySQL as DB to store all the values. There is a chance that a privileged user can change the values in the DB by editing using the basic UI provided by MySQL. Is there any way to know when and who changes the values in logs or any other file that store DB transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the General [MySQL log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html), in my.cnf define log=< path> and restart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check it.